# ComboBox ItemsSource binding not updated after value selected

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox in WPF binding its ItemsSource Property to a Property returning an IEnumerable of String. The binding is just one-way. The class that contains the data for the ComboBox implements INotifyPropertyChanged Interface and calls the OnPropertyChanged(..) as soon as the Property gets updated. When I leave the ComboBox untouched the changes are correctly propagated. But as soon as the ComboBox is expanded once or a value is selected the changes in the ItemsSource Collection are no longer updated. What may be the reason for this behaviour?

Heres the XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbSourceNames" 
          Grid.Row="0" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceAddresses, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
```

The DataContext is set in the code behind:

```
this.cmbSourceNames.DataContext = this._dpa;
```

And this one is the Method that triggers the change of the Property. The Method for adding the Packet is delegated to the Current Dispatcher with BeginInvoke.

```
private void DispatcherAddDataPacket(DataPacket dp)
{
    ObservableCollection<DataPacket> dpList;
    this._dpkts.TryGetValue(dp.SourceAddress, out dpList);
    if (dpList == null)
    {
        dpList = new ObservableCollection<DataPacket>();
        dpList.Add(dp);
        this._dpkts.Add(dp.SourceAddress, dpList);
        OnPropertyChanged("SourceAddresses");
    }
    else
    {
        dpList.Add(dp);
    }
}
```

The Property is giving back the Keys of the Dictionary as IEnumerable.

Comment: Please post the XAML.

Comment: Post your binding code. Its better to bind selectedIndex to a property in viewmodel

Comment: Made an edit with the XAML and some code snippets

Comment: @Jasti: I can imagine that but in this case it is a little bit more convenient because I may use the binding directly as the dictionary key

Comment: @Jasti: I also tried the code with the Binding to SelectedItem completely removed. But this did not change anything.

Comment: Did you get the solution. I was sidetracked by my personal work. You mentioned changes were not propagating, are these from combobox to property(code behind) or vice versa. Why are you not going for two way binding if you want to propagate changes in both the directions. Can you be more specific on this.

Comment: @Jasti: I just need a one-way binding for the ItemsSource Property because the dictionary keys are extended dynamically as soon as a Package with another SourceAddress is added. I extract the keys of a Dictionary as the ItemsSource and update a chart and a data table (which are two-way bound) with data belonging to these keys selected with the binding to SelectedItem. The interesting thing is that the binding initially works but only until you expand the ComboBox for the first time...I really have no clue what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented the Binding Property using an ObservableCollection tracking the keys when a new Packet gets added (so every key to the Dictionary has an equivalent in this ObservableCollection). I think it's not really a satisfying solution (because you have to keep track of both Collections independently) but it works like this.